# I am trying to figure out why my code is giving me an extra line in my output?

Tags: python, function

I am trying to figure out why my code is giving me an extra line in my output? I have tried several different methods but this is the only code I have managed to get together to give me the results I want but I am trying to get rid of the last row in my output, any suggestions?

```
def get_square_pattern(max_rows):
    emoji = ''
    result = ''
    max_cols = max_rows
    for row in range(1, max_rows+1):
        for column in range(1, max_cols+1):
            print(emoji, end=' ')
            result += emoji
        print()
    return result


print(get_square_pattern(5))
Output:
```

Comment: To get rid of last printed (returned) row, you can call the function without printing the output of the function, with `get_square_pattern(5)` instead of `print(get_square_pattern(5))`.

Comment: why not use a debugger and determine the moment the extra line is shown in the output

Answer (score 1):

You can simply remove the result variable (since it's not needed for printing) and modify the loop as follows:

```
def get_square_pattern(max_rows):
    emoji = ''
    max_cols = max_rows
    for row in range(1, max_rows + 1):
        for column in range(1, max_cols + 1):
            print(emoji, end=' ')
        print()


get_square_pattern(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do the printing within the function then there's no need to return a value.

Just do this:

```
def get_square_pattern(max_rows, emoji=''):
    print(*[emoji*max_rows]*max_rows, sep='\n')

get_square_pattern(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

def get_square_pattern(max_rows):
emoji = ''

```
max_cols = max_rows
for row in range(1, max_rows + 1):
    for column in range(1, max_cols + 1):
        print(emoji, end=' ')
        
    print()
```

get_square_pattern(5)

Answer (score 0):

```py
    
    def get_square_pattern(max_rows):
        emoji = ''
        result = ''
        max_cols = max_rows
        for row in range(1, max_rows+1):
            for column in range(1, max_cols+1):
                # print(emoji, end=' ') # Don't print
                result += emoji
            # print()  # Don't print
            result += '\n' # After each row add a new line
        return result


    print(get_square_pattern(5))
```

If you add a new line to `result` after each row you will have your desired output.

I've also commented the print statements inside the loop since you return `result` and print that in `print(get_square_pattern(5))`

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_square_pattern(max_rows=1):
    result = ""
    max_cols = max_rows
    for row in range(1, max_rows+1):
        for column in range(1, max_cols+1):
            result += ""
        result += "\n"
    return result
```

Turns out I was not allowed to print() within the function or for loops. I also needed to make sure that max_rows was defaulted to 1. Furthermore, I didn't need to print the get_square_pattern() function because I was only allowed to do so to test the output results to match the ones provided. Thanks for your help everyone!